# Problem importing collada model

Tags: mesh, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Recently i made a model of a tunnel in blender that looks like this:[image: image description]
I exported it to a Collada file but when i load the model into gazebo some parts of the model disappeared.[image: image description]
I am using gazebo 2.2.3.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14542/problem-importing-collada-model/) by [jbga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2668/jbga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like some of the normals are flipped. Try visualizing them in Blender and changing them where appropriate.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2668/jbga/) on 2016-10-03**:
I flipped the normals and it worked. Thank you